# How to convert dictionary<string,int> to double array of their values in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, double, int, toarray

In my programming i have a challenge..

```
Dictionary<string,int> dic=new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

now i need to convert those dictionary "values" to 'Double' array.

i tried like this,

```
string[] strn=dic.Values.ToArray();
```

but not working. can any one please resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duh, you're trying to store a collection of ints as an array, into an array of strings; of course that would never work. And what exactly do you mean by "double array"? Two arrays, or an array of doubles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
double[] strn = dic.Values.Select(v => (double)v).ToArray();
```

...and ignore people who are unkind enough to say "duh" :)

Answer (score 7):

```
double[] dd = dic.Values.Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
```